# Why uitableviewcell changing when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have button on uitableviewcell which have target on function like this:

```
likeButton?.addTarget(self, action: "likeButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

inside the function I set my button title like this:

```
sender.setTitle("\(addedLikeCount) Likes", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

But whenever I scroll the view up or down, my button title change to it's default. Why is that happen? Is there any way I can fix this without reloading table?

Feel free to give me any advice, doesn't matter in swift or objective c.

**UPDATE**

So I did code below on my function:

```
self.likeArray.replaceObjectAtIndex(index!, withObject: addedLikeCount)

sender.setTitle("\(self.likeArray[index!]) Likes", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

And this on my uitableviewcell:

```
var totalLike = likeArray[indexPath.row] as? String

currentLikeCount = totalLike

likeButton?.setTitle("\(totalLike)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

It worked, but when I scroll the tittle become default again

Comment: because the cell is being reuse and therefore refreshed to its original setup under `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`, solution is to have a global variable then setup on reload under `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: How can I do that without reloaddata?

Comment: get the superview(cell) were the pressed `likeButton` is and  then change/set the title but do not reload the table and do not scroll else it will be reused and refresh again, that's the natural behavior of tableview (for memory handling).. meaning in your case.. that's your only option.. :)

Comment: okay I see, is it possible that I only reloaddata on one row??

Comment: YES using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` please refer from this link about [UITableView Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/).. haha. i should have post this as an answer shouldn't i? haha

Answer (score 2):

Tableview cell reloads everytime it's will be shown on the screen after scroll.
You must provide reusable identifier for your cell on you storyboard or XIB
Objective-C variant:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"your_cell_identifier_on_storyboard_or_cell_xib";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    /// datasource code here

    return cell;

}
```

If you want to store all your context for specific indexpath, as on your question - to hold all buttons caption, use

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:
```

instead of

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

Warning: dequeuing cells for specific indexpath may slow performance

Answer (score 1):

Do you use this in your code ?

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifer")
```

If yes, you have to save the state of each cell.

Because every time you scroll up and down, TableView will bring back the previous cell that outside of the screen.

What you need is setting the new state of the cell correspond to `indexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method something like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifer") as? UITableViewCell{

        cell.title = titles[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error, xcode can't found the return if I put return inside if statement

Comment: put return UITableViewCell() at the end of function

Answer (score 0):

As Oyeoj commented

Cell is changing because "the cell is being reuse and therefore refreshed to its original setup under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, solution is to have a global variable then setup on reload under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`."

For your desired task you have to store selected cell index some where i.e. your button on `someIndex` cell has `Likes` title.

for Objective-C

in .h

`NSMutableArray likeArray;`

in .m

in `viewDidLoad`

`likeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check

```
 if ([likeArray containObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
 {
    [button setTitle:@"Likes", forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 }
 else
 {
    [button setTitle:@"Some Other Title", forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -

```
NSNumber *cellIndex=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
if(![likeArray containObject:cellIndex])
{
    [likeArray addObject:cellIndex];
}
[table reloadData];
```

Comment: I edited my question, and I already try your solution but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which check for which row the title is changed and vice versa.For eg

```
-(BOOL)checkForSelectedRow:(NSIndexPath *)path
```

Now Create array which store for which button the title is changed,So whenever the button is tapped u add it to the array in your `likeButtonTapped`

Now in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if([self checkForSelectedRow:indexPath]){
//change the title of button

}
else{
 //default of button
}
```